# The program expected this account to be already initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, solana

I'm using the [Solana](https://pub.dev/packages/solana) package with Jupiter swap token. After getting the swap result. I'm executing a transaction synchronously with the Solana package sendTransaction method at that time. I'm getting the below error code.

Jupiter [Swagger](https://quote-api.jup.ag/docs/static/index.html) collection.

`{accounts: null, err: {InstructionError: [0, {Custom: 3012}]}, logs: [Program JUP3c2Uh3WA4Ng34tw6kPd2G4C5BB21Xo36Je1s32Ph invoke [1], Program log: Instruction: SetTokenLedger, Program log: AnchorError caused by account: token_account. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized., Program JUP3c2Uh3WA4Ng34tw6kPd2G4C5BB21Xo36Je1s32Ph consumed 5139 of 600000 compute units, Program JUP3c2Uh3WA4Ng34tw6kPd2G4C5BB21Xo36Je1s32Ph failed: custom program error: 0xbc4], unitsConsumed: 0}`

Answer (score 0):

Jupiter can create up to 3 transactions (setupTransaction, swapTransaction, cleanupTransaction). Make sure that you execute all of them (if they are not null) in this order.